# 2.92.0 bug? EEVEE AOVs are not fully opaque

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Been using aovs in the experimental 2.92 version in eevee to export EXRs for compositing in Nuke and even though all my materials are have alphas of one, the AOV layers have a max alpha of 0.984. Example attached below.

[image]
[image: alpha is in fact 1.00]
[image: in Nuke the max value is always 0.984 when it should be 1.00]

In Nuke the max value is always 0.984 when it should be 1.00

Comment: Try switching the ColorRamp from _linear_ to _constant_ - you could be getting the slightest amount of bleed-over from  the linear interpolation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to reproduce, [bug report has been filed](https://developer.blender.org/T85261).  ColorRamp wasn't the issue.